# How to style my unordered list like a table?

Tags: html, css

I have ONLY one `<UL>` and under that we have group of `<LI>`

```
 <ul>
   <li>1<li>
   <li>2<li>

   <li>3</li>
   <li>4<li>

 </ul>
```

now I wanted to show them as TABLE, please help me with CSS, how can we show as a TABLE for above UL/LI in below table format, 2 LI set in one TR (two TD) and so on....

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using a table rather than an unordered list?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: You cannot make CSS do HTML work. What you can do, however, is styling your unordered list so that it will be represented as table.

Comment: how to do that styling so that UL/LI represented as TABLE...I also want to break 2 LI into a single TR...also want to show heading?

Comment: @user584018 [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Unwh6/) one possible solution; is it that what you want?

Comment: I would just ask you: Why do you want to use ul/li instead of a standard table?  Because if the data you have in that list is tabular data, you SHOULD use a table.

Comment: @raina...some how it is very close, but can our lines exactly same as table...any way thanx

Comment: @steve, I m applying jquery UI sortable which works great with UL/LI rather than TABLE, but i need to show a table look for UL/LI

Comment: @user584018 maybe you should consider using a library that works on tables.  Stuffing tabular data into a list is just as bad as using tables for layout.

Comment: @user584018 - If you are using jQuery sortable for a table, you are using it wrong.  Sortable is meant to sort a list of single elements, not a complex table structure. There are much better plugins to achieve what you are trying to do. Maybe [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) or [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, here's one possible solution:

```
ul {
    width: 450px;           /* change it to whatever you like */
    position: relative;

    /* these should be probably already set up by `reset.css` */ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul:before, ul:after {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 48%;
}

ul:before {
    content: 'col1';
    border-right: 0;    
}

ul:after {
    content: 'col2';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 48%;
    margin-left: 1px;    
}

li {
    text-align: right;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

It works ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unwh6/1/); tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera; `nth-child(even)` selector obviously fails in IE8, so you have to emulate it with class or other means; but otherwise it's still solid), but I admit I feel guilty about this. )

P.S. If you want to add padding to the "cell" contents, don't forget to change their widths as well, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Unwh6/2/):

```
li {
    width: 47%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: To my (mild) amusement, it actually [works ok](http://jsfiddle.net/Unwh6/4/) with $.sortable: at least the table doesn't start to fall apart. )

Comment: That's pretty impressive. :) However, as expected, it sorts the table by cell, not by row (which I guess was the intend of the OP).

Comment: @raina...WOW perfect for my scanario!

Answer (score 4):

It's a really late answer, but I think this is a common topic. [Here's a codepen I made](http://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/CxgiH).

Obviously it's just a starting point. It also has some example of how to add styles like bg or borders. If the 'cells' contain some arbitrary content, you'll have to adjust dimensions, for example. I use this kind of code for thumbnails galleries, for example, where you don't have to worry about borders or bgs and it's quite elementary code (the example is for a 2x3 table, see codepen):

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n){
  background-color:#888;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n+1){
  clear:both;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  background-color:#ccc;
}

ul li:nth-child(-n+3){
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a single list (containing more than 2 items) into 2 columns via the `display: table` properties because you need some element to act as the table-row.  Without an element acting as a table-row, all adjacent elements that are set to `display: table-cell` will be contained within an anonymous table-row element that cannot be modified or styled in any way.

Your only option is to either change the markup (to use tables or lists of lists) or use a different approach to your CSS:  either floats/inline-block on the `li`s or using the `columns` property on the `ul`.