# Formatting div into table

Tags: html, css, xslt

So, I have a unique case where I'm using xslt to generate many (~50-100) div elements depending on the day from an xml like this:

```
<div class="allApps" >
    Content here
</div>
<div class="allApps" >
    Content Here also
</div>
...
```

I currently have them formatted into rounded boxes stacked vertically. How can I use css to position them into a "tabular" format, like fitting 5 in a row?

Alternatively, they were initially `<li>` instead of `<div>`. How could I implement tables with `<li>`?

The reason I'm doing this is to reduce the amount of scrolling required to get to the bottom of the elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to reduce the vertical scroll then try to make some of them as

```
display:inline-block
```

You could make them all inline-block and then insert breaks every so often (like every 5th one).  Or, if you want some great responsive options you could use Bootstrap.

If you are really set on using a table then li's have nothing to do with it.  Li elements are for a list, not a table.  Cells in a table use td like

```
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But honestly, the easiest thing is probably to just switch to css display:inline-block.

Comment: I don't have the authority to change the xslt. So there's no way for me to insert a break. I'm looking for something like this, but for multiple (3 or more) columns: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824918/how-to-style-my-unordered-list-like-a-table)[link]

Comment: You can use jQuery to insert breaks where needed.  Or, since inline-block will automatically break to fit a page, maybe that will work ok by itself.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle of what I'm talking about.  

https://jsfiddle.net/od8tqfg6/

You can comment out the jQuery  to see what the inline-block does by itself.